# MaterialEditText RegexpValidator

Tags: java, android, regex

How do I get this code to check if the input is valid and set z2 = true, if the input in valid instead of the charSequence.length?

I am using this lib:

https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

```
    this.inputDisplayName.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("You can only use Laters and Numbers", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"){
        public boolean isValid(CharSequence charSequence, boolean z) {
            boolean z2 = false;
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(charSequence)) {
                RegisterActivity.this.displaynameVerified = false;
            } else {
                RegisterActivity registerActivity = RegisterActivity.this;
                if (charSequence.length() >= 8) {
                    z2 = true;
                }
                registerActivity.displaynameVerified = z2;
            }
            RegisterActivity.this.validateInput();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `RegexpValidator` already has a valid implementation of `isValid`... Why are you overriding it and never using the regex feature of it?

Comment: Because I want to set displaynameVerified = true; if there is no error

Comment: Have you tried assigning that value to if the pattern matches? https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/rengwuxian/materialedittext/validation/RegexpValidator.java#L26

Comment: How do I do that in my script?

Comment: Well, `registerActivity.displaynameVerified = this.pattern.matches(...)` would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the RegexValidation entirely to do nothing with the regex given.

Personally, I would suggest you extend it and add a callback using an interface.

```
/*
* Add these inside the class
*/

private static interface ValidCallback {
    public void isValid(Boolean valid);
}

private static class NumberLetterValidator extends RegexpValidator { 

    private ValidCallback c;

    public NumberLetterValidator(ValidCallback c) {
        super("You can only use Laters and Numbers", "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CharSequence charSequence, boolean isEmpty) {
        boolean valid = super.isValid(charSequence, isEmpty);
        if (c != null) c.isValid(valid);
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Then, you  can pass your custom logic through there.

```
ValidCallback cb = new ValidCallback() {
    @Override
    public void isValid(Boolean b) {
        displaynameVerified = b;   
        validateInput();
    }
};
this.inputDisplayName.addValidator(new NumberLetterValidator(cb));
```